# What are the limitations of Vmware Player for Personal Use vs. Pro?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I'm trying to decide between using VirtualBox or Vmware's free (for  non commercial user) [Workstation Player](https://www.vmware.com/products/player/)
I can't find out what a "restricted virtual machine" is anywhere.

I currently have Vmware Player (free/home) version 5 and it's fine. Wanted to make sure that version 12 didn't have some crippleware.

> Workstation 12 Player is licensed for commercial use and is enabled to
>   run restricted virtual machines. If you simply want to learn more
>   about virtual machines or run virtual machines at home in a
>   non-commercial environment you may use Workstation 12 Player at no
>   cost. - See more at:

https://www.vmware.com/products/player/#sthash.iVRgNZ7n.dpuf

Comment: Product feature separation has not really changed just the name of the free version of the software (workstation)

Comment: Note to close voters: I don't think this is a software recommendation, since it's asking about specific features of some programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**vmWare moved features from the free Workstation Player to Workstation Pro**

vmWare Player v 5 lets me also use Workstation 9.

the latest vmWare Workstation Player appears to be missing the Snapshots feature from vmware Workstation 9. That's a pretty important feature for me.

Answer (score -1):

[Direct Image comparison VMware Workstation Player vs VMware Workstation Pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6X235.png)
Sourse:https://www.nakivo.com/blog/vmware-workstation-pro-vs-player/

VMware Workstation Player and Workstation Pro are virtualization applications that users can run in their desktop or laptops. One is free (Player) and the other is licensed (Workstation). Both run on top of the host Operation System like in Windows or Linux systems.

These two virtualization applications are different since Workstation Player is more a basic and non-commercial tool and Workstation Pro is more advanced and professional virtualization solution to create and manage Virtual Machines.

The hardware and Host Operation Systems requirements for these two virtualization applications are the same.

Host requirements to install VMware Workstation Player and Workstation Pro:

Minimum:

CPU: 1GHz 64-bit processor
Memory: 2Gb RAM
Recommended (mainly if running multiple Virtual Machines):

CPU: 2GHz 64-bit processor
Memory: 4Gb RAM
Disk space:

For Workstation Player: 150Mb

For Workstation Pro: 1,2Gb

Note: Additional CPU, Memory and hard disk space, are required for each virtual machine.

Comment: `For Workstation Pro: 1,2Gb`? `For Workstation Pro: 1.2Gb`? `For Workstation Pro: 1-2Gb`?

Comment: @Ramhound the source of the table was added.